# Can OSMIUM export all relations like OSMOSIS is doing?

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, osmosis, osmium

I have been working with OSMOSIS for quite some time and love that I have the freedom to work on the raw data of OpenStreetMap. I am utilizing any kind of information in order to normalize the data in PostgreSQL.

Now I have started to investigate alternatives which can process the PBF files a bit quicker. I have found OSMIUM which is really fast and provides also a lot of configuration options. But I realized that it does some things which I do not want, like creating polygons and not retaining relations for points and ways (like e.g. all features which belong to some public transport station, etc.).

I simply would like to have one table with all features (nodes and ways) and it´s tags plus the relation information (maybe also in a separate table, referencing the IDs of the nodes and ways).

Is this somehow possible?

What I am currently doing is

```
osmium export somewhere.osm.pbf -c osmium.config -f pg -o somewhere.osm.pg  -O -v -n -e
```

With following config file:

```
{
"attributes": {
    "type":      true,
    "id":        true,
    "version":   true,
    "changeset": true,
    "timestamp": true,
    "uid":       true,
    "user":      true,
    "way_nodes": true
},
"format_options": {
    "tags_type": "hstore"
},
"linear_tags":  true,
"area_tags":    true,
"exclude_tags": [],
"include_tags": []
```

}

Thanks a lot for any kind of help!